# pytumblr ImportError: No module named pytumblr

Tags: python, api, python-2.7

I receive the error "ImportError: No module name pytumblr" when trying to run a python script using Tumblr's api.

I installed pytumblr using the following:

```
sudo pip install pytumblr
```

My script looks like this:

```
import pytumblr
client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient(
'<consumer_key>',
'<consumer_secret>',
'<oauth_token>',
'<oauth_secret>',
)

client.info()
```

NOTE: The parameters in the TumblrRestClient method are properly filled out in my script.

I'm new to python and have never used an API or installed a module before. I have a hunch that the module is not found because pytumblr was not installed in the proper directory that the script searches when making the import call.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Works for me... probably something went wrong when you installed it - try re-installing.

Comment: Maybe you installed pytumblr into another version of Python?

Comment: Are you sure the installation went through correctly? Maybe try `easy_install pytumblr` ?

Comment: Using `sudo easy_install pytumblr` worked for me. I also had to use `print client.info()` to actually see the results. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

1. Uninstall any existing packages with `sudo pip uninstall oauth oauth2 pytumblr`
2. Reinstall with `sudo pip install oauth oauth2 pytumblr`

Also, check your Python version correlates to the PIP you are using. You can use `python --version` and `pip --version` to check.